# How do I pass additional dependencies to a React custom hook

Tags: reactjs

I am using a custom hook to load initial data into components. It works fine but I get a warning because I pass dynamically constructed dependencies to my useEffect hook:
React Hook useEffect was passed a dependency list that is not an array literal. This means we can't statically verify whether you've passed the correct dependencies

[image]

Here is the code for my custom hook:

```js
const useApiData = (path: string, dependancies: any[], defaultValue: any) => {
    const client = useApi();
    const modelTemplate = {
        isLoading: true,
        data: defaultValue ? defaultValue : null
    };

    const [model, setModel] = useState(modelTemplate);
    const dependencies: any[] = dependancies ? [...dependancies, client, path, model.isLoading] : [client, path, model.isLoading];

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!model.isLoading) {
            setModel({ isLoading: true, data: null });
        }
        client.get(path).then(data => {
            setModel({ isLoading: false, data: data });
        }).catch(error => {
            //do nothing, errors will be shown in notifications
        });
    }, dependencies);

    return model;
}
```

And here is an example of passing an additional dependency:

```js
const product = useApiData(`/products/${productId}`, [model.reviewAdded]);
```

In this component I am showing a product details and its reviews. I want to update the product details when a review gets added because the product rating gets changed. Can I do this with using my custom hook and not receiving a warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is lint issue.
It seems that you are using ts-lint, according to your files extensions (*.ts).
In my project, I have similar custom hooks but I use es-lint. With es-lint, I did the next:

1. Disable warning inside hook via:

```
const useCustomHook = (deps) => {
  useEffect(() => {
   doStuff(deps)

  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, deps)
}
```

2. Add custom hook to default validator so that es-lint treats custom hook as out-of-the-box hook and do static checks:

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
 rules: {
   'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': [
     'error',
     {
       additionalHooks: 'useCustomHook',
     },
   ],
 },
}
```

I believe, you can do something similar for ts-lint